# No puedo iterar una lista porque la clase no es iterable

Tags: python, poo

Tengo una clase, que simplemente tiene un atributo que es una lista, esta lista a su vez, guarda otras instancias de objetos. La cuestión es que el for para recorrer la lista, me dice que no es iterable. No entiendo porque, ya lo he probado con otro código, y si me funciono, alguien logra ver el error?

He probado cambiar la forma de llamar al metodo, que tal vez estoy llamando mal en el main, pero no lo logro hacer funcionar, cree una lista de 2 objetos, 1, o ninguno, y me sigue fallando, no se si el error estara directamente en el foro para recorrer la lista, o en otro lugar, como en la clase Vehiculo, alguna variable mal declarada que no logro ver.

```
class Vehiculo ():
       def 
__init__(self,identificador,modelo,km_total,km_dia,ultima_mantencion,presion_neumaticos,operarios,accidente):
        self.__identificador=identificador
        self.__modelo=modelo
        self.__km_total=km_total
        self.__km_dia=km_dia
        self.__ultima_mantencion=ultima_mantencion
        self.__presion_neumaticos=presion_neumaticos
        self.__operarios=operarios
        self.__accidente=accidente
    #Getters
    def get_modelo(self):
        return self.modelo
    def get_km_total(self):
        return self.km_total
    def get_km_dia(self):
        return self.km_dia
    def get_ultima_mantecion(self):
        return self.ultima_mantecion
    def get_presion_neumaticos(self):
        return self.presion_neumaticos
    def get_operarios(self):
        return self.operarios
    def get_accidente(self):
        return self.accidente
    def get_identificador(self):
        return self.identificador
    
    #Setters
    def set_modelo(self,modelo=""):
        self.__modelo=modelo
    def set_km_total(self,km_total):
        self.__km_total=km_total
    def set_km_dia(self,km_dia):
        self.__km_dia=km_dia
    def set_ultima_mantecion(self,ultima_mantecion):
        self.__ultima_mantencion=ultima_mantecion
    def set_presion_neumaticos(self,presion_neumaticos):
        self.__presion_neumaticos=presion_neumaticos
    def set_operarios(self,operarios):
        self.__operarios=operarios
    def set_accidente(self,accidente):
        self.__accidente=accidente
    def set_identificador(self,identificador):
        self.__identificador=identificador
def Mostrar_Datos(self):
        print("\nDatos del Vehiculo\n")
        print("\tIdentificador: ",self.__identificador)
        print("\tModelo: ",self.__modelo)
        print("\tKilometros totales: ",self.__km_total)
        print("\tKilometros del dia: ",self.__km_dia)
        print("\tUltima mantención: ",self.__ultima_mantencion)
        print("\tPresion neumaticos: ",self.__presion_neumaticos)
        print("\tOperarios: ",self.__operarios[0],self.__operarios[1],self.__operarios[2])
        print("\tAccidentes: ",self.__accidente)

class ParquedeVehiculos():
    def __init__(self,lista_vehiculos=[]):
        self.__lista_vehiculos=lista_vehiculos
    #Getters
    def get_lista_vehiculos(self):
        return self.__lista_vehiculos
    #Setters
    def set_lista_vehiculos(self,lista_vehiculos):
        self.__lista_vehiculos=lista_vehiculos
    def Mostrar_Datos(lista):
        print("Lista total de vehiculos\n")
        j=1
        for i in lista:
            tipo=type(i)
            if tipo == Vehiculo:
                print("\nDatos vehiculo numero: ", j)
                Vehiculo.Mostrar_Datos(i)
            else:
                print("\nDatos grua numero: ", j)
                Grua.Mostrar_Datos(i)
            j+=1`
```

Este es el archivo principal, desde donde llamo el metodo, cabe destacar que todas las clases tienen metodo mostrar datos.

```
    from Vehiculo import Vehiculo
from Grua import Grua
from Estacionamiento import ParquedeVehiculos

loll= Vehiculo("850","modelo","4","54","394",[1,1,1,1],["1","2","2","pepe"],"si")
lol2= Vehiculo("850","modelo","4","54","374",[1,1,1,1],["1","2","2","pepe"],"si")
lista1=[loll,lol2]
minera=ParquedeVehiculos()
minera.set_lista_vehiculos(lista1)
minera.Mostrar_Datos()
```

Comment: no se mucho python.. pero que es el parametro lista?

Comment: El parámetro lista es un array de instancias de clase Vehículo

Comment: y donde esta? como llamas a esa funcion? si te dice que no es iterable, es porque no es una lista...

Comment: La llamo en un archivo principal de esta manera.
loll= Vehiculo("850","modelo","4","54","394",[1,1,1,1],["1","2","2","pepe"],"si")
lol2= Vehiculo("850","modelo","4","54","374",[1,1,1,1],["1","2","2","pepe"],"si")
minera=ParquedeVehiculos([loll,lol2])
minera.Mostrar_Datos()

Comment: usa el boton [edit] para agregar datos a la pregunta.. yo veo mal, o mostrar datos recibe como parametro una lista??????

Comment: Añadi la edición de donde llamo el metodo, si, recibe como parametro una lista, pero segun he probado, si es una lista, probe haciendolo de la forma larga, como esta en el adjunto, para que efectivamente sea una lista, pero aun asi sigue sin funcionar

Comment: no recibe nada de nada.. si no le estas mandando nada...

Comment: Tenes que ver el tipo de dato que estás recibiendo, si te dice que no es iterable es xq no es una lista. El método Mostrar_Datos no tiene el "self", por lo tanto lo que está recibiendo bajo el nombre de "lista" es la instancia. Y por último, cuando llamas a "Mostrar_Datos" no le estás pasando nada y recibe de manera mandatoria una lista.

Answer (score 1):

El error pasa porque falta `self` al método `Mostrar_Datos()`. Si lo arreglas de la forma `Mostrar_Datos(self, lista)`, tendrás que pasarle (otra vez) la lista de objetos desde el llamado al método, lo cual parece bastante raro ya que tienes un *setter* en la línea previa, pasando esos mismos objetos.

Entonces, la solución sería: (1) Colocar `self` en la definición del método y (2) en el `for` usar el atributo que tiene los objetos, definido en el setter.

```py
    def Mostrar_Datos(self): # <-- cambios
        print("Lista total de vehiculos\n")
        j=1
        for i in self.__lista_vehiculos: # <-- cambios
            # etc ...
```